# XSS in Angular Translate Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xss, angular-translate

In my project I'm using '*escape*' as the sanitize value strategy. And I'm using translate directive (attribute) in some place. Some other places I'm using translate filter.

**With Directive:**

```
<span translate="{{vm.text}}"><span>
```

This is vulnarable to XSS. If the value of `vm.text` is `<script>alert()</script>` , then the script is executed and the popup is shown.

**with Filter**:

```
<span>{{vm.text | translate}}<span>
```

The value of `vm.text` is escaped and the html is shown as `&lt;script&gt;alert()&lt;/script&gt;`

In angular translate documentation (https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/19_security) they recommend using 'escape' as the sanitize value strategy saying '***Currently there is an issue with the sanitize mode, it will double encode UTF-8 characters or special characters. Recommendation: use the 'escape' strategy, until this is resolved***'.

Is there a proper way to show the html as `<script>alert()</script>` without executing it?

Comment: I have found when using the filter it escapes correctly but will not escape this kind of attack:  #/{{{}.")));alert(1)//";}}  Using the directive will correctly escape this kind of attack but then it fails on the script attack that you illustrate. So for me this is a big hole in the translate library.

Answer (score 0):

With the filter (pipe) you could always bind to the elements `textContent` property like so:

`<span [textContent]="vm.text | translate"></span>`

No manual escaping or filtering needed because nothing in textContent is ever parsed afaik.

Comment: what version of angular is this for?